# Allowed Baggage size in emirates between India and USA

Tags: luggage, indian-citizens, jfk, emirates

My journey is from Bangalore, India (BLR) to New York, USA (JFK) via Dubai in Emirates (Economy Flex). I have an *American Tourister* bag and the model is same as this [[Link](http://www.snapdeal.com/product/american-tourister-26r068003-grey-82cm/329893256)]. The Length + Width + Height is 164 cm. But when I checked Emirates itinerary, it clearly mentions 150 cm (or 59 inch) [[Link](http://www.emirates.com/in/english/plan_book/essential_information/baggages/baggage_calculator_result.aspx?departure=blr&arrival=jfk&class=yf&tier=sn&h=778bbf135dc692beeda051b39a61b84f0b9e0ae)] as allowed limit for check-in baggage.

Can any frequent flyer comment if this is safe to travel or Emirates will be very particular about the dimensions?

Comment: It also says oversize luggage will be carried for a fee, so you don't have to worry about it left behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emirates has the following to say about this, on their [website](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/baggages/checked-baggage.aspx):

> If your journey includes any destinations in Canada, North America or
>   South America, different baggage rules apply.
>
> The total dimensions (length + width + height) of each piece must not
>   exceed 150cm (59 inches). You’ll be charged an additional fee for any
>   individual items exceeding dimensions of 150cm (59 inches), up to a
>   maximum of 300cm (118 inches). If an individual item has total
>   dimensions greater than 300cm (118 inches), it can’t be checked in as
>   baggage and will need to be sent as cargo or freight.
>
> If you check in two pieces of luggage (in any of our three classes),
>   the total combined dimensions of both pieces should not exceed 300cm
>   (118 inches).
>
> For travel to and from Canada and North America, you can check in two
>   bags of up to 23kg each in Economy Class, and two bags of up to 32kg
>   each in First Class or Business Class.

Therefore, in your case you bag will be accepted, but you'll be charged a fee as it exceeds the dimensions.

Emirates provides a [baggage fee calculator](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/baggages/baggage_calculator.aspx), but this only allows you to purchase extra baggage at a discount. It does not display rates for oversize baggage:

> **The checked baggage allowance and excess baggage rates calculator is for your information only. Overweight and oversize charges might
>   apply. Please contact your local Emirates office for more information.

Comment: It would be good to point out what the fee is

Comment: Actually my real question is --- "will they really enforce these dimension checks?"  I certainly agree that weight will be strictly adhered to the limits. But I want to know if dimensions are even checked in reality

Comment: Yes they will, as the item will be too big to go through the normal luggage flow; and some restrictions are there not by Emirates but by the airport. In the US individual items checked in **cannot** exceed 32KG since this is the limit of the baggage handling systems.

Comment: It's interesting that Emirates sets their limit at 150 cm. Most of the U.S. and European airlines use a limit of 158 cm (62 inches), so I imagine that not being able to go through the equipment isn't much of a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Emirates employ two types of baggage concept; the first is Weight Concept, and the second Piece Concept. The piece concept is applied when a journey is to any of the destinations in Canada, North America, and South America.

Since your Journey is to a destination (that is New York) in the States, Piece Concept applies.

According to this concept for Economy Class, two pieces of luggage weighing 23 kg each is checked-in. When it comes to dimensions, the total dimensions (height, width, length) of an individual piece should not exceed 150 cm or 59 inches. However, in your case, the total dimensions exceed by 14 cm. Hence, excess baggage allowance is charged.

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry about that much of a size difference. The maximum possibility is that if they think your hand-carry is too large they will ask you to book it with the luggage instead of taking it in the cabin.

source: i have traveled approximately 40 times between Oman and Pakistan using OmanAir, QatarAirways and Flydubai.

Comment: It's already hold luggage, not carry on.

Comment: in that case there won't be any issues

Comment: How do you know there won't be any issues?

Comment: personal experience

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more please? This could be a great answer if you say e.g. "I have flown this trip x times with a similarly oversized suitcase and never had any problems."